# How many consecutive integers have consecutive divisors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

For each positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the number of positive integers pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+i$ divides $b+i$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$. What is the growth rate of $f(n)$?

Comment: Every pair for $n$ is also a pair for $n-1$ and $(a+1,b+1)$ is too, so $f(n)$ is strictly decreasing assuming it is finite.

Comment: As written, it is always infinite because $(a,a)$ is always a pair for every $n$ and every $a$, right?

Comment: @AlexS:  even simpler than my answer.  I think you should make it an answer.  I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n$ there are infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying the requirement.  We can simply take $a=1$.  This requires $n$ lines of $$b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 2
\\b+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\b+3 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$ and so on.  The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guarantees an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For every positive integer $a$, $(a,a)$ is a pair for all $n$. So $f(n)$ is always infinite.